# Sorting fractions into ascending order in C language

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, fractions

My program presents three options to the user. The first option lets the user enter a numerator and then a denominator. The second option displays those fractions that i have enter. Now for the third option it is suppose to sort it in order from smallest to biggest fraction. I have been stuck on this for a while, not sure what to do

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Struct to hold fraction data
typedef struct
{
    int numerator, denom;
}fraction;

double Calc_Frac(fraction b)
{
    return((double)b.numerator / b.denom);
}

int main()
{
    //Array of 100 fractions
    fraction arrFraction[100];

    int i = 0;
    int j;
    int num = 1;

    while (num == 1)
    {
        int choice;
        printf("\nPress 1 to enter a fraction\n");
        printf("Press 2 to view stored fractions\n");
        printf("Press 3 to sort fractions\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if(choice == 1)
        {
            //Prompting user
            printf("\nEnter your fraction, numerator followed by   denominator\n");

            //Reading values from user
            scanf("%d %d", &arrFraction[i].numerator, &arrFraction[i].denom);

            //Incrementing counter
            i++;

        }

        if (choice == 2) 
        {
            printf("-------------------------\n");
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) 
            {
                printf("%d  %d/%d \n",      arrFraction[j].numerator/arrFraction[j].denom,  
                    arrFraction[j].numerator%arrFraction[j].denom,  arrFraction[j].denom);
            }
            printf("\n-------------------------\n\n");
         }

        if (choice == 3)
        {
            int min;
            fraction tmp;

            for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
            {
                min = i;
                for (j = i + 1; j < i; j++)
                {
                    if (Calc_Frac(arrFraction[j]) < Calc_Frac(arrFraction[min]))
                    {
                        min = j;
                    }
                }
                tmp = arrFraction[i];
                arrFraction[i] = arrFraction[min];
                arrFraction[min] = tmp;
            }
            i++;
        }

   } // end of while loop

  system("pause");

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to check for zero denominator

Comment: Your sorting code outer for loop is depending on j i.e. `i < j` . But what is the value of j ? It will change depending on whether the user entered option 2.

Comment: I'd suggest first taking the sorting logic and running it independently to see if it actually sorts correctly.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315424/sorrting-of-fractions-in-ascending-order-c-language. In fact, I think you're the same user (airdemko3 -> ademko)

Comment: Making multiple accounts to ask the same question is bad practice

Comment: Note also that you didn't ask a question. And don't forget to include a link to this page when you turn in your assignment. You don't want to be guilty of academic dishonesty, after all.

Answer (score 1):

In choice 3,

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (Calc_Frac(arrFraction[j]) < Calc_Frac(arrFraction[min]))
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        tmp = arrFraction[i];
        arrFraction[i] = arrFraction[min];
        arrFraction[min] = tmp;
    }
    i++;
```

is messed up because you are reusing variables where you can't. If `i` is supposed to be your counter, then you are destroying that value here. Along with `j`, use a separate counter variable and preserve `i`.

```
for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
    {
        min = k;
        for (j = k + 1; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (Calc_Frac(arrFraction[j]) < Calc_Frac(arrFraction[min]))
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        tmp = arrFraction[k];
        arrFraction[k] = arrFraction[min];
        arrFraction[min] = tmp;
    }
```

Moreover, there is no need for the second increment of `i` at thw end.

Some of the other issues are:

1. Remember to check whether the denominator is zero when you accept the values.
2. Give the user an option to exit from the program. Currently, the while loop is infinite, as the value of `num` is never updated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take input both numerator, denominator and check for denominator not to be zero and if this is zero then give the user a message that the number should be greater than zero:

```
scanf("%d",&numerator[i]);
if(denominator[i]<=0){
   printf("Enter denominator greater than zero ");}
else{
  scanf("%d",&denominator[i]);
 }
```

After storing all the inputs, 
make sure the number of numbers input in both numerator and denominator must be equal, say **n**. Now multiply all the numbers of denominator and store it in a variable that must be a **long type** say **multi_long**. Next task is to divide the multi_long by denominator and multiply it with numerator and store it in a new array.

```
array_new[i]=(multi_long/denominator[i])*numerator[i];
```

since by sorting this array using bubble sort we can easily find the greatest and smallest number as the new_array[i] element is small in any index at the same index in denominator[] and numerator[] will have.
In bubble sort, when you are finding the biggest element in array the in one loop it only finds only one number that is greater.

Comment: This isn't a particularly good idea.  It is inherently limited to small lists of fractions as the multiplication soon yields values that are too big for built-in types.  Yes, you could use multi-precision arithmetic libraries; No, that really isn't necessary.  Using bubble sort is usually not a good idea either.